# Bootstrap slider animation issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm working with a bootstrap slider and the images are there, they switch every few seconds, almost everything works fine. But it won't display the animation, it's like suddenly it'll change the image. Here's the code:

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'img/slider1.png' %}" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'img/slider2.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'img/slider3.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
     </div>
```

Note: I'm using Django and I loaded {% static %} previously, so that isn't the issue. I also inserted the scripts from bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known issue with the latest Bootstrap v4.1

Try to downgrade to v4.0, that would work

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Use the CDN for BS 4.0 in your `<script>` where you are currently including v4.1